# How to retrieve ISIN from yahoo-symbol in python or query-string?

Tags: yahoo-finance, yahoo

As I can retrieve the yahoo-symbol from any ISIN with

```
def get_symbol_for_isin(isin):
    url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/search'
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.109 Safari/537.36',
    }
    params = dict(
        q=isin,
        quotesCount=1,
        newsCount=0,
        listsCount=0,
        quotesQueryId='tss_match_phrase_query'
    )
    resp = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, params=params)
    data = resp.json()
    if 'quotes' in data and len(data['quotes']) > 0:
        return data['quotes'][0]['symbol']
    else:
        return None
```

I wonder if it is possible to write a function in the other direction to receive an ISIN fram a yahoo symbol?

I did google the net for any function of "import yfinance" but did nothing find.